# Linux add new line before and after a matched pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I want to put newline before "< script" and after < /script> tags in an HTML file.

```
sed 's/<script/\'$'\n/g'
```

I tried that one but it deleted "script" tags.

Sample input:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>JavaScript Ders 2</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript"></script> <script></script> </head><body> <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript"></script> </body></html>
```

Sample output:

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>JavaScript Ders 2</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> 
<script>
</script> 
</head><body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> 
</body></html>
```

What I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're just doing this to make it easier to read, rather than attempting to format HTML using sed...

To add newlines before `<script` and `</script` (assuming that your version of sed understands `\n`):

```
sed -E 's|</?script|\n&|g' file
```

Match `</?script` (`/?` makes the `/` optional) and replace with a newline, followed by the full match `&`.

It doesn't quite match the output in your question since it looks like you want to put each opening/closing `<script>` tag on its own line, rather than just insert lines:

```
$ sed -E 's|</?script|\n&|g' file
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>JavaScript Ders 2</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> 
<script>
</script> </head><body> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" language="javascript">
</script> </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted any samples so couldn't test it, could you please try following and let me know then.

```
sed 's/<script>/\n&/;s/<\/script>/&\n/' Input_file
```

Let's say following is Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
<script>
fewvfewvvew
</script>
abcd
```

Then after executing code we will get following output then.

```
<script>
fewvfewvvew
</script>

abcd
```

Comment: @unh, try to select an answer(after sometime of your post) among all answers as correct answer to close the post fully.

Comment: @unh, from a single line to multiple lines you want to do? then you may need a html parser, sed is not right tool for it then.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that for minified HTML